# Javascript Regex - How can I delete words with an uppercase letter in the middle?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a raw string that contains a sentence, and I am trying to remove every word that has an uppercase letter **in the middle** of it.

Example :
`"I like strawBerries"` would return `"I like"`

but `"I like Strawberries"` would retrun `"I like Strawberries"`

I found the following regex: `\B[A-Z]\B`
But it only matches the upper cases inside the words, not the words themselves...

Comment: Consume the letters, `\b[a-z]+[A-Z][a-zA-Z]+\b` or `\b[a-z]+[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*\b` if the uppercase letter can appear at the end of a word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the expression `\w+[A-Z]\w*`, it matches any word containing at least 1 capital letter in any position except the first.

It'll match all of:

- xyZ
- xYz
- xYZ
- XyZ
- XYz
- XYZ

But not:

- xyz
- Xyz

```js
let string = 'This is NOT a RainBow, it is, in faCt, a sTrABerry cakE.';
//  Removed:          xxx   xxxxxxx            xxxx    xxxxxxxxx xxxx
// 'This' is kept.

let out = string.replace(/\w+[A-Z]\w*/g, '');

console.log(out);
```

Comment: Works very well too but I may not have been specific enough, the only scenario where the word should be removed is "xYz" - the answer provided by Wiktor Stribiżew is perfect for me. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

you can do it using non caturing groups as:

```
const regex = /(?:\w+[A-Z]\w+)|(?:\w+[A-Z])|(?:[A-Z]\w+)/gm;
const str = `I like strawBerries. my name is Taimoor `;
const subst = ``;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
// Substitution result: I like . my name is
```

`\w` matches any word character (equivalent to [a-zA-Z0-9_])
`+` matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
`[A-Z]` -
`A-Z` matches a single character in the range between A (index 65) and Z (index 90) (case sensitive)
`(?:...)` is Non-capturing group

Answer (score 0):

Use

```js
/\s*\b[a-z]+[A-Z][a-zA-Z]+\b/g
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/7qCyIS/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [a-z]+                   any character of: 'a' to 'z' (1 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [A-Z]                    any character of: 'A' to 'Z'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [a-zA-Z]+                any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z'
                           (1 or more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
```

**JavaScript snippet**:

```js
["I like strawBerries", "I like Strawberries"].forEach(x =>
    console.log(x.replace(/\s*\b[a-z]+[A-Z][a-zA-Z]+\b/g, '').trim())
)
```